# how to make a recycler view scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a recycler view scrollable in my xml layout file
but it does not scroll

here is what I have tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data class=".ProductsBinding">
        <variable
            name="productsViewModel"
            type="com.xxx.xx.ProductsViewModel" />
    </data>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ProductsFragment">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/products_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Can you please suggest how to get this to work please

thanks
R

Comment: please try to  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of the `NestedScrollView` , if not worked, also try to `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` in `RecyclerView`

Comment: @Zain i tried that but did not work, I updated my xml file again in my question

Comment: @Zain tried that but did not work

Comment: can you add `android:fillViewport="true"` to `NestedScrollView`

Comment: tried that @Zain but did not work

Comment: `RecyclerView` is scrollable by default. Remove the `NestedScrollView` and give the `RecyclerView` a fixed height (anything but `wrap_content`). See [this Java project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v1.1/RecyclerViewBasics) or [its Kotlin counterpart](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v1.1/RecyclerViewBasics) for small samples showing the use of `RecyclerView`.

Comment: thank you for your advices it is working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, if you have only RecyclerView as child, why use NestedScrollView??

anyway how about this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data class=".ProductsBinding">
        <variable
            name="productsViewModel"
            type="com.xxx.xx.ProductsViewModel" />
    </data>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ProductsFragment">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <LinearLayout
              android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
               android:id="@+id/products_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

add linearLayout in NestedScrollView

CF] If you use a recycler view within a double scroll view, the recycler view will generate all the items in advance. (You can check the log from the onBindViewHolder on the RecycleView Adapter.) Also, because we don't recycle Item View, we lose the big advantage of Recycling View, which can increase memory efficiency by reusing View, so be sure to keep that in mind. If you have a lot of items, avoid using them.

Comment: usually you don't need NestedScrollView when only scrollable view as child